# laravel setup error: mbstring not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am just beginning with laravel. I followed all the steps mentioned in here: http://github.com/aimeos/aimeos-laravel and tried running the final project using this command:

> php artisan serve

It is giving me an error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/
[Wed Apr 13 17:03:32 2016] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 13 17:03:43 2016] 127.0.0.1:39822 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Wed Apr 13 17:03:43 2016] 127.0.0.1:39823 [200]: /favicon.ico
```

What should I do to resolve this error? I have installed mbstring library so I think it should've been able to find it.

I am using laravel 5.2.29.

EDIT:
I had uncommented the line:

> extension=php_mbstring.dll

in my php.ini file which shouldn't be done if platform is UNIX. Now, when I run `php artisan serve` on terminal, it doesn't give any error. But when I go to localhost:8000, it says : Whoops! looks like something went wrong.

EDIT2:
Did everything according to suggestion.
Now the error is: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

What I have already tried:

> 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
>
> php artisan key:generate

What can be done to resolve it?

Comment: Is you're machine running Windows or Linux? Because the error states that it's trying to load a DLL (which is a Windows library) from a path that looks like it's from Linux.

Comment: Also, does the list output form running `php -m` in your console contain the item `mbstring`?

Comment: If you run `php -i | grep -i "Loaded Configuration File"` in the output you'll get a path to the `php.ini` configuration file that PHP is loading. If you check that file does it contain any line with `php_mbstring.dll`?

Comment: But you didn't answer my question, does that `php.ini` file contain any line that has `php_mbstring.dll` in it?

Comment: Yes it does. The line is : extension=php_mbstring.dll

Comment: Then **that line should be commented** (have a `;` at the beginning) because it should be used only if you were running Windows.

Comment: Thanks, so the error is gone. But now when I go to localhost:8000, it says : Whoops! looks like something went wrong. There is no error msg on terminal now.

Comment: Make sure you've enabled debug mode in your Laravel `.env` file by setting `APP_DEBUG=true`. Then you'll get a complete stack trace showing the file and line where the error originates. Also run `php artisan serve` again after you've modified the `.env` file, so it can pick up the changes.

Comment: Unless this is being deployed to a Windows Server, i'm shocked people still use this XAMPP approach to development over the elegant Vagrant and homestead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got my last problem resolved too.
The problem was that as @Bordon suggested, I had created a `.env` file. But when I ran the command:

> php artisan key:generate

It created another file called .env.example. Now since I am a user of composer, I needed to rename it to .env (and remove the prev one).

So finally I renamed it, ran the above mentioned command again and now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot @Bordon for helping me out. 
Also I would like to note that as @ash suggested, using Vagrant is quite a lot easier to me than xampp.